# Angular (7+) Material table with expandable rows - multiple expanded rows at the same time

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am using [Material table with expandable row](https://stackblitz.com/angular/yoeqvrjkraq?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts)

I would like to have multiple rows expanded on row clicks. The default behavior is to close the previously expanded row upon a new row click. I don't want the previous ones to be closed, each should be left open until clicked again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is another approach.

Simply make the variable an array

```
expandedElement: PeriodicElement[] = [];
```

On the animation section use a function instead of direct checking

```
[@detailExpand]="checkExpanded(element) ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
```

And use the same function while adding the class

```
[class.example-expanded-row]="checkExpanded(element)"
```

And on click make a function call. If the element is present remove it from the array and if not present add it

```
(click)="pushPopElement(element)"
```

And here are the 2 functions which are used. Please feel free to improve efficiency of the methods. Its a crude method written in a short time for the demo.

```
checkExpanded(element): boolean {
    let flag = false;
    this.expandedElement.forEach(e => {
      if(e === element) {
        flag = true;

      }
    });
    return flag;
  }

  pushPopElement(element) {
    const index = this.expandedElement.indexOf(element);
    console.log(index);
    if(index === -1) {
        this.expandedElement.push(element);
    } else {
      this.expandedElement.splice(index,1);
    }
  }
```

You can find the working sample here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6jz81

Answer (score 4):

For achieving this, you have to add one more properties in the data source like `expanded:true`, and then change on row click , toggle this property in the data source, and based on this property change the class in the HTML for expansion.

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkt6ny?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts)

Added code snippet in case link breaks.

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {
    ...
    expanded: false
  },
  {
    ...
    expanded: false
  }
]
```

On click of the row, simply toggle `expanded` property (Loop is not required), also add class based on the same `expanded` property.

```
<div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element.expanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
...
</div>

<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="element.expanded"
      (click)="element.expanded = !element.expanded">
</tr>
```